# Does a Powerset-over-Reader monad exist?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

The canonical 'Monad instance' for environment sharing plus nondeterminism is as follows (using pseudo-Haskell, since Haskell's `Data.Set` isn't, of course, monadic):

```
eta :: a -> r -> {a} -- '{a}' means the type of a set of a's
eta x = \r -> {x}

bind :: (r -> {a}) -> (a -> r -> {b}) -> r -> {b}
m `bind` f = \r -> {v | x ∈ m r, v ∈ f x r}
```

Generally, when trying to combine a 'container' monad like Powerset (List, Writer, etc) with a second monad `m` (here, roughly, Reader), one 'wraps' `m` around the container monad, as done above.

I wonder, then, about the following potential Powerset-over-Reader specification:

```
eta' :: a -> {r -> a}
eta' x = {\r -> x}

bind' :: {r -> a} -> (a -> {r -> b}) -> {r -> b}
m `bind'` f = {rb | x <- m, ∀r: ∃rb' ∈ f (x r): rb r == rb' r}
```

This doesn't seem obviously crazy (I do realize that GHCi can't check `rb r == rb' r` for many `rb` and `rb'`), but `bind'` is complicated enough to make it difficult (for me) to check whether the monad laws hold.

My question, then, is whether `eta'` and `bind'` really are monadic -- and, if not, which of the law(s) is violated, and what sort of unexpected behavior might this correspond to?

A secondary question, assuming that `eta'` and `bind'` aren't monadic, is how one might ascertain *whether* there are functions with these types that are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fun question. Here is my take -- let's see if I didn't goof anywhere!

To begin with, I will spell your signatures in (slightly less pseudo) Haskell:

```
return :: a -> PSet (r -> a)
(>>=) :: PSet (r -> a) -> (a -> PSet (r -> b)) -> PSet (r -> b))
```

Before continuing, it is worth mentioning two practical complications. Firstly, as you have already observed, thanks to `Eq` and/or `Ord` constraints it is non-trivial to give sets `Functor` or `Monad` instances; in any case, [there are ways around it](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/set-monad.html). Secondly, and more worryingly, with the type you propose for `(>>=)` it is necessary to extract `a`s from `PSet (r -> a)` *without having any obvious supply of `r`s* -- or, in other words, your `(>>=)` demands a traversal of the function functor `(->) r`. That, of course, is not possible in the general case, and tends to be impractical even when possible -- at least as far as Haskell is concerned. In any case, for our speculative purposes it is fine to suppose we can traverse `(->) r` by applying the function to all possible `r` values. I will indicate this through a hand-wavy `universe :: PSet r` set, named in tribute to [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe.html). I will also make use of an `universe :: PSet (r -> b)`, and assume we can tell whether two `r -> b` functions agree on a certain `r` even without requiring an `Eq` constraint. (The pseudo-Haskell is getting quite fake indeed!)

Preliminary remarks made, here are my pseudo-Haskell versions of your methods:

```
return :: a -> PSet (r -> a)
return x = singleton (const x)

(>>=) :: PSet (r -> a) -> (a -> PSet (r -> b)) -> PSet (r -> b))
m >>= f = unionMap (\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (f (x r)))
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) m
    where
    unionMap f = unions . map f
    intersectionMap f = intersections . map f
```

Next, the monad laws:

```
m >>= return = m
return y >>= f = f y
m >>= f >>= g = m >>= \y -> f y >>= g
```

(By the way, when doing this sort of thing it is good to keep in mind the other presentations of the class we are working with -- in this case, we have `join` and `(>=>)` as alternatives to `(>>=)` -- as switching presentations might make working with your instance of choice more pleasant. Here I will stick with the `(>>=)` presentation of `Monad`.)

Onwards to the first law...

```
m >>= return = m
m >>= return -- LHS
unionMap (\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (singleton (const (x r))))
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) m
unionMap (\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            const (x r) r == rb r)
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) m
unionMap (\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            x r == rb r)
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) m
-- In other words, rb has to agree with x for all r. 
unionMap (\x -> singleton x) m
m -- RHS
```

One down, two to go.

```
return y >>= f = f y
return y -- LHS
unionMap (\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (f (x r)))
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) (singleton (const y))
(\x ->
    intersectionMap (\r ->
        filter (\rb -> 
            any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (f (x r)))
            (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
        (universe :: PSet r)) (const y)
intersectionMap (\r ->
    filter (\rb -> 
        any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (f (const y r)))
        (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
    (universe :: PSet r)
intersectionMap (\r ->
    filter (\rb -> 
        any (\rb' -> rb' r == rb r) (f y)))
        (universe :: PSet (r -> b)))
    (universe :: PSet r)
-- This set includes all functions that agree with at least one function
-- from (f y) at each r.
```

`return y >>= f`, therefore, might possibly be a much larger set than `f y`. We have a violation of the second law; therefore, we don't have a monad -- at least not with the instance proposed here.

---

Appendix: here is an actual, runnable implementation of your functions, which is usable enough at least for playing with small types. It takes advantage of the aforementioned [*universe*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0) package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module FunSet where

import Data.Universe
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Int
import Data.Bool

-- FunSet and its would-be monad instance

newtype FunSet r a = FunSet { runFunSet :: Set (Fun r a) }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

fsreturn :: (Finite a, Finite r, Ord r) => a -> FunSet r a
fsreturn x = FunSet (S.singleton (toFun (const x)))

-- Perhaps we should think of a better name for this...
fsbind :: forall r a b.
    (Ord r, Finite r, Ord a, Ord b, Finite b, Eq b)
    => FunSet r a -> (a -> FunSet r b) -> FunSet r b
fsbind (FunSet s) f = FunSet $
    unionMap (\x ->
        intersectionMap (\r ->
            S.filter (\rb ->
                any (\rb' -> funApply rb' r == funApply rb r)
                    ((runFunSet . f) (funApply x r)))
                (universeF' :: Set (Fun r b)))
            (universeF' :: Set r)) s

toFunSet :: (Finite r, Finite a, Ord r, Ord a) => [r -> a] -> FunSet r a
toFunSet = FunSet . S.fromList . fmap toFun

-- Materialised functions

newtype Fun r a = Fun { unFun :: Map r a }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Functor)

instance (Finite r, Ord r, Universe a) => Universe (Fun r a) where
    universe = fmap (Fun . (\f ->
        foldr (\x m ->
            M.insert x (f x) m) M.empty universe))
        universe

instance (Finite r, Ord r, Finite a) => Finite (Fun r a) where
    universeF = universe

funApply :: Ord r => Fun r a -> r -> a
funApply f r = maybe
    (error "funApply: Partial functions are not fun")
    id (M.lookup r (unFun f))

toFun :: (Finite r, Finite a, Ord r) => (r -> a) -> Fun r a
toFun f = Fun (M.fromList (fmap ((,) <$> id <*> f) universeF))

-- Set utilities

unionMap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> Set b) -> (Set a -> Set b)
unionMap f = S.foldl S.union S.empty . S.map f

-- Note that this is partial. Since for our immediate purposes the only
-- consequence is that r in FunSet r a cannot be Void, I didn't bother
-- with making it cleaner.
intersectionMap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> Set b) -> (Set a -> Set b)
intersectionMap f s = case ss of
    [] -> error "intersectionMap: Intersection of empty set of sets"
    _ -> foldl1 S.intersection ss
    where
    ss = S.toList (S.map f s)

universeF' :: (Finite a, Ord a) => Set a
universeF' = S.fromList universeF

-- Demo

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let andor = toFunSet [uncurry (&&), uncurry (||)]
    print andor -- Two truth tables
    print $ funApply (toFun (2+)) (3 :: Int8) -- 5
    print $ (S.map (flip funApply (7 :: Int8)) . runFunSet)
        (fsreturn (Just True)) -- fromList [Just True]
    -- First monad law demo
    print $ fsbind andor fsreturn == andor -- True
    -- Second monad law demo
    let twoToFour = [ bool (Left False) (Left True)
                    , bool (Left False) (Right False)]
        decider b = toFunSet
            (fmap (. bool (uncurry (&&)) (uncurry (||)) b) twoToFour)
    print $ fsbind (fsreturn True) decider == decider True -- False (!)
```

Comment: How does the definition of `>>=` correspond to the `bind'` in the OP? Where are the quantifiers, and the guard containing the equality comparison? With the original pseudocode, `m >>= return` is `{rb | x <- m, ∀r: rb r == x r}` which really is just `m` in the theory of sets. It may not be possible to capture precisely the given semantics in actual Haskell, but I don't think the question is asking about that.

Comment: I think I agree with the above comment. In the OP `bind'`, `f (x r)` and `rb r` both receive the same environment `r`. I don't see how that's guaranteed by your (still quite lovely) `>>=`.

Comment: @user2407038 [1/2] In the pseudo-Haskell above, the quantifier is represented by `fromList [minBound..maxBound]`, meant as a set containing all possible `r` values. That said...

Comment: ... [2/2] as you and @SimonC point out, I omitted the equality because I misunderstood the definition. Let's remove the wrong parts and see if I can work out something better.

Comment: @SimonC Okay, take two :) I think I got it right this time. As anticipated by user2407038, the first law does hold.

Comment: @SimonC After an arduous battle with the quantifier shift fallacy, I *think* I got this right. However, now I feel compelled to get something like it to actually run...

Comment: @duplode Great update! I think your code is a great argument for why this would be entirely impractical, even if the sans-`Ord` constraint set and `universe` semantics where easy to implement - `>>=` performs four potentially very expensive nested traversals (two over the entire universe) so even if it was running, it would probably take longer than the age of the universe for any sets with more than a handful of elements... if you get it to run with non-horrible asymptotics, that would be truly fantastic...

Comment: Yes, wonderful. I can't help but noticing that the issue here parallels one discussed [here](http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/SALT/article/view/2901/2641). I would still love to know how one might ascertain whether there could/couldn't be monadic operations with these types.

Comment: @user2407038 The asymptotics are quite horrifying indeed, but in any case I have appended an *universe*-based toy implementation to the answer -- and it does seem to work! (I didn't have the courage to feed it a large type yet, though :))

Comment: @SimonC Thank you for the reference -- though I'm not familiar with the subject matter, I'll make sure to read that paper. Questions about ways of making sense of function traversals have been at the back of my mind for quite a while. By the way, I have just appended a implementation/demo to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is somewhat easier to verify the laws in Kleisli notation.

```
kleisli' :: (a -> {r -> b}) -> (b -> {r -> c}) -> (a -> {r -> c})
g `kleisli'` f = \z -> {rb | x <- g z, ∀r: ∃rb' ∈ f (x r): rb r == rb' r}
```

Let's try to verify `` return `kleisli'` f = f ``.

```
(\a -> {\r->a}) `kleisli'` f = 
\z -> {rb | x <- {\r->z}, ∀r: ∃rb' ∈ f (x r): rb r == rb' r} = 
\z -> {rb | ∀r: ∃rb' ∈ f z: rb r == rb' r}
```

Say all of our types `a`, `b`, `c` and `r` are `Integer` and `f x = {const x, const -x}`. What functions are in `` (return `kleisli'` f) 5 ``? This set should be `f 5`, that is, `{const 5, const -5}`.

Is it? Naturally `const 5` and `const -5` are both in, but not only. For example, `\r->if even r then 5 else -5` is also in.

Comment: Good example, and it is nice to also have here a verification with a different presentation of `Monad` and more compact notation.