# Is the composition of an arbitrary monad with a traversable always a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

If I have two monads `m` and `n`, and `n` is traversable, do I necessarily have a composite `m`-over-`n` monad?

More formally, here's what I have in mind:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor.Compose

prebind :: (Monad m, Monad n) =>
         m (n a) -> (a -> m (n b)) -> m (n (m (n b)))
mnx `prebind` f = do nx <- mnx
                     return $ do x <- nx
                                 return $ f x

instance (Monad m, Monad n, Traversable n) => Monad (Compose m n) where
  return = Compose . return . return
  Compose mnmnx >>= f = Compose $ do nmnx <- mnmnx `prebind` (getCompose . f)
                                     nnx  <- sequence nmnx
                                     return $ join nnx
```

Naturally, this type-checks, and I believe works for a few cases that I checked (Reader over List, State over List) -- as in, the composed 'monad' satisfies the monad laws -- but I'm unsure if this is a *general* recipe for layering any monad over a traversable one.

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/ttt.pdf) is a great book which covers this topic from the perspective of category theory (in particular, p257 "Distributive laws") and gives a *relatively* (from the point of view of someone who already knows category theory...) simple proof of the necessary condition for `M . N` to be a monad if `M` and `N` are monads. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453915/composing-monads-v-applicative-functors) is another question which presents a slight variation on the code you have given - perhaps it would be a more useful starting point.

Comment: Spoiler: it is.

Comment: Lol, thank you! I had read that thread not all that long ago, but missed [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453915/composing-monads-v-applicative-functors#comment47075703_29454112), which contains a positive answer.

Comment: It is somewhat sad, if obvious in retrospect, that layering State over List in this way doesn't give you *nondeterministic state*, in contrast to what happens when you layer StateT over List.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would ever ascribe the word *sad* to a mathematical result (unless you are saying the result makes *you* sad) .. However, there probably is a different property for which, if it holds, then `M . N` and `N . M` are isomorphic monads. What that property is, I don't know - but if it interests you and you investigate it a bit, it would probably make another good question.

Comment: If `Traversable n` is the perfect constraint to make this work, it would be nice if `Data.Functor.Compose` had the instance. Maybe you should suggest it? I can definitely think of a context where I might use it.

Comment: Aside from the obvious point that the laws would need to be proved for arbitrary traversables (beyond my pay grade), it was pointed out to me that `instance ... => Monad (Compose m n) where ...` would prevent any other monad instances for `Compose` from being defined (on pain of overlapping instances). So the instance here would need to be totally general. Is it?

Comment: Yes, that's why I began 'if Traversable n is the perfect constraint ...' Maybe that was a little obscure. We don't want more than one instance surely, just the most general (correct) one.

Comment: It seems like `Representable n` or `Distributive n` (or something like that with few types that are also monads) is more the correct constraint, which is a drag. One should have guessed this from the reputation of `ListT`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not always a monad. You need extra compatibility conditions relating the monad operations of the two monads and the distributive law `sequence :: n (m a) -> m (n a)`, as described for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_law_between_monads).

[Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262575/does-a-powerset-over-reader-monad-exist) gives an example in which the compatibility conditions are not met, namely

S = `m = []`, with unit X -> SX sending x to [x];

T = `n = (->) Bool`, or equivalently TX = X × X, with unit X -> TX sending x to (x,x).

The bottom right diagram on the Wikipedia page does not commute, since the composition S -> TS -> ST sends `xs :: [a]` to `(xs,xs)` and then to the Cartesian product of all pairs drawn from `xs`; while the right-hand map S -> ST sends `xs` to the "diagonal" consisting of only the pairs `(x,x)` for `x` in `xs`. It is the same problem that caused your proposed monad to not satisfy one of the unit laws.

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious. Since `[]` is traversable, but `(->) r` isn't, the recipes above would provide a way to derive a Reader-over-List  (or Set) monad, but not a List-over-Reader monad, which is what my previous question was asking about.

Comment: Sorry, I see now why `(->) Bool` is indeed traversable. Is `(->) r` traversable, for any finite `r` (along the lines hinted at in the question you linked to)?

Comment: `(->) Bool`, or `(->) r` for any finite type `r`, is traversable since it's equivalent to an `|r|`-tuple.

Comment: A quick followup. Is the *if* in the wiki article you linked a literal *if* (the existence of a distributive law is a sufficient condition on the composite functor being monadic) or a mathematician's *if* (sufficient, and necessary)?

Comment: I checked that the bottom-right diagram is necessary for ST to be a monad in the specified way (it follows from unit laws for S, T, and ST). I'm guessing that the other diagrams can be proved to be necessary in a similar fashion, since they are also equations between morphisms to ST, but I don't see any particular reason to think a priori that they *must* be necessary.

Comment: [This code](https://gist.github.com/schar/3b640ec63cedb84b1221d7363f3099bf) is just  an unpacking of Reid's excellent answer, but I found it helpful to work through a concrete case. (It is still rather surprising to me that things go awry in this way, since the relevant `sequence` operation in the non-monadic case seems to preserve information.) Incidentally, Reid's point here seems under-appreciated. SO is full of comments to the effect that traversability is precisely the required constraint on the inner monad.

Comment: To be honest, I was vaguely under the same impression until I spent a while thinking about your other question.

Answer (score 5):

A few additional remarks, to make the connection between [Reid Barton's general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298943/2751851) and your concrete question more explicit.

In this case, it really pays off to work out your `Monad` instance in terms of `join`:

```
join' ::  m (n (m (n b))) -> m (n b)
join' = fmap join . join . fmap sequence
```

By reintroducing `compose`/`getCompose` in the appropriate places and using `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`, you can verify that this is indeed equivalent to your definition (note that your `prebind` amounts to the `fmap f` in that equation).

This definition makes it comfortable to verify the laws with diagrams<sup>1</sup>. Here is one for `join . return = id` i.e. `(fmap join . join . fmap sequence) . (return . return) = id`:

```
3210
  MT  id     MT  id    MT  id   MT
     ---->      ---->     ---->
 rT2 |   |  rT1 |   | rT1 |   | id
 rM3 V   V  rM3 V   V     V   V
     ---->      ---->     ---->
MTMT  sM2  MMTT  jM2  MTT  jT0  MT
```

The overall rectangle is the monad law:

```
 M   id   M
    ---->     
rM1 |   | id 
    V   V  
    ---->     
 MM  jM0  M
```

Ignoring the parts that are necessarily the same both ways across the squares, we see that the two rightmost squares amount to the same law. (It is of course a little silly to call these "squares" and "rectangles", given all the `id` sides they have, but it fits better my limited ASCII art skills.) The first square, though, amounts to `sequence . return = fmap return`, which is the lower right diagram in the Wikipedia page Reid Barton mentions...

```
 M   id   M
    ---->     
rT1 |   | rT0 
    V   V  
    ---->     
 TM  sM1  MT
```

... and it is not a given that that holds, as Reid Barton's answer shows.

If we apply the same strategy to the `join . fmap return = id` law, the upper right diagram, `sequence . fmap return = return`, shows up -- that, however, is not a problem in and of itself, as that is just (an immediate consequence of) the identity law of `Traversable`. Finally, doing the same thing with the `join . fmap join = join . join` law makes the other two diagrams -- `sequence . fmap join = join . fmap sequence . sequence` and `sequence . join = fmap join . sequence . fmap sequence` -- spring forth.

---

Footnotes:

1. Legend for the shorthand: `r` is `return`, `s` is `sequence` and `j` is `join`. The upper case letters and numbers after the function abbreviations disambiguate the involved monad and the position its introduced or changed layer *ends up at* -- in the case of `s`, that refers to what is *initially* the inner layer, as in this case we know that the outer layer is always a `T`. The layers are numbered from bottom to top, starting from zero. Composition is indicated by writing the shorthand for the second function below the first one.