# Idiomatic way to implement "m (t a) -> (a -> m (t b)) -> m (t b)"

Tags: haskell, monads, idioms, io-monad

The `bind` function (`>>=`) has the signature:

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

However, I want a function with the signature:

```
m (t a) -> (a -> m (t b)) -> m (t b)
```

Specifically, I have a function that given an Integer, it returns a list of integers in within an IO:

```
f :: Int -> IO [Int]
```

but I want to apply it to an `IO of list of Integers` and I can't use the regular bind function because it is wrapped in two containers i.e. a list contained in an IO. [Searching on hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=m+%28t+a%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+%28t+b%29%29+-%3E+m+%28t+b%29) doesn't help.

I am using the following approach to implement this:

Let's say the implementation of the function is:

```
f :: Int -> IO [Int]
f x = do
  return $ [x-10, x+10]
```

I am using two helper functions to get what I want:

```
f' :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
f' xs = do
  list <- traverse f xs
  return $ join list

f'' :: IO [Int] -> IO [Int]
f'' xs = do
  ys <- xs
  f' ys
```

The above works but I would like to know if there is a better / idiomatic way to implement this in haskell?

Comment: I am not looking for a solution since I already have that. I want an idiomatic way to solve this.

Comment: I don't know if you've read the answers yet, but *"More generally, what function has type m1 m2 a -> (a -> m1 m2 b) -> m1 m2 b?"* is part of that duplicate question. The answer: it's impossible in the general case. See the second answer.

Comment: If you remove the type signatures on `f'` and `f''` and abstract `f` into a parameter, you'll get the most general type inferred by the typechecker. I would say these implementations are idiomatic, except perhaps the use of `do` notation instead of `>>=` and `fmap` but those are purely stylistic concerns. As it stands, this question is entirely opinion based - can you clarify what about your code is not good enough, i.e., what you'd like to see the 'better' version accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic solution would be to use `Data.Functor.Compose`:

```
data Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

Since the function you're looking for is trivial to implement when `Compose f g` is a monad:

```
bibind :: Monad (Compose f g) => f (g a) -> (a -> f (g b)) -> f (g b)
bibind m h = getCompose (Compose m >>= Compose . h)
```

As well explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454112/9859), it's not sufficient
for `f` and `g` to be `Monad`s, they also need to commute:

```
class Commute f g where
  commute :: g (f x) -> f (g x)

instance (Monad f, Monad g, Commute f g) => Monad (Compose f g) where
  return = Compose . return . return
  join = Compose .  fmap join .  join .  fmap commute . getCompose . fmap getCompose
```

(In general, [it's not sufficient for `f` to be a monad and `g` to be `Traversable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298943/9859))