# Can nested monad be a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to make two nested monad to a monad, but can not find the solution.
I can make it `Functor` and `Applicative`, but can not find a way to make it a `monad`

```
newtype Man m n a = Man { runMan :: m (n a) }  -- Man means M And N

instance (Functor m, Functor n) => Functor (Man m n) where
  fmap f (Man mnx) = Man $ fmap (fmap f) mnx

instance (Applicative m, Applicative n) => Applicative (Man m n) where
  pure = Man . pure . pure
  (Man mnf) <*> (Man mnx) = Man $ liftA2 g mnf mnx
    where g p x = p <*> x
```

My question is : How can I make it a monad , or Why it can not be a monad?

```
instance (Monad m, Monad n) => Monad (Man m n) where
  (Man mnx) >>= f = undefined
```

I tried it for several hours, and recognized it may be a mission impossible at last, so I want to know why?

Comment: Also relevant: [*Is the composition of an arbitrary monad with a traversable always a monad?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42284879/2751851)